# Swipe navigation from a sub native stack

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I have an app structure looks like this

```yaml
# Native Stack
 - root
   # Bottom tab
   - Main tab
     # Native Stack
     - First tab
     - Sec tab
   - Sec tab
     # Native Stack
     - First tab
     - Sec tab
 - Login
   # Native stack
   - LogIn
   - Register
 - NotFound
```

So I have a `native-stack` under a `bottom stack`, which is also under the root `native-stack` and I want to switch between `firstTab` and `secondTab` with finger swiping, so I can return to the previous tab after navigating it. But somehow it doesn't work. The finger swiping only works for the `root` native stack.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

## Solved

It was a dumb question from me. I have solved it by using `navigation.push` instead of using `navigation.navigate`.

If someone is wondering it too, then try this solution :)